# Passing checked checkboxes through to next form

Tags: php, javascript, forms, checkbox

Is there a way for checked checkboxes to pass through to the next form as a checked checkbox? I know you can code for radio buttons with:
`<?php echo (isset($register) && $register == 'no') ? ' checked' : '' ; ?>`

There are multiple checkboxes for one one name and different values. So when viewed in the email, it just loops to show the values of the checkboxes. But before I send the email, I want the checkboxes to be checked (if they were checked in the previous form) as if there was an error in the form.

Is there a way to make sure the checkboxes you have selected are selected in the next form? Either in php or javascript?

Comment: only checked checkboxes will be processed. so no need to check for values

Answer (score 0):

You can check and set checkboxes in the same way that you set radio controls as long as you set a value for the checkbox.

If you do not set a checkbox value, checked checkboxes will contain the value of 'on'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the names and values as below mentioned and check the checked options

```
<input type="checkbox" name="interests1" value="Food"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="interests2" value="Movies"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="interests3" value="Music"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="interests4" value="Sports">
```

for checking use get/post as:

```
 if(isset($_GET['intreset1'])){
   //something here
 }
```